# Testcase of Regex is failing

Tags: java, regex

I've got the following regex:

```
^[EC]D_V_[a-zA-Z]{5}____([0-9]{8})_[0-9]{3}_[a-zA-Z](_[0-9]{1,7})?\.([^<>:\\”\/\\|\\*\\?]{3,4})(\.gz)?
```

and this testdata:

```
CD_V_DoSto____00000000_255_A_952086.445 
ED_V_DoSto____99999999_255_A_91459._416.gz
```

Why is the second one failing, but if I edit the first file to `CD_V_DoSto____00000000_255_A_952086.445.gz` it's working.

I think the `0-9{8}` is causing the problem, but I couldnt verify it...

Here you can test it: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uMA4nY/1)

Comment: Tried adding `m` modifier (so that `^` could match the start of a *line*)? Try https://regex101.com/r/twEQNK/1, I also changed `([^<>:\\”\/\\|\\*\\?]{3,4})` to `([^.<>:”\/|*?]{3,4})` so that the group pattern could not match a `.`. Do you need to match `.gz` in the second string?

Comment: Sorry, I'm no regex expert, what exactly is that doing?

Comment: Start of a line, I updated my first comment. Please see and let know what exact output you need for the second string.

Comment: Answer the question so I can take it as a solution, Thanks man!

Comment: But do you need to capture `.gz` into Group 4 in the second string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew gz is optional, some doesn't have it, but both should be valid. Yes, I need to capture it if it's present.
`(\.gz)?` is doing the job as 4th capture group, no?

Comment: Ok, so it is not a dupe then. I posted an answer with all points covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three things to consider here:

- The `^` anchor only matches the start of the string by default, to make it match the line start, you need to prepend the pattern with `(?m)` or use the `m` multiline option
- The Group 3 pattern requires any 3 or 4 chars but those in the set, but since the `{3,4}` quantifier is greedy, the `.` before `gz` gets matched and `.gz` does not fall into Group 4. You should add `.` to the negated character set
- If the whole string should match, do not forget to use `$` in the regex tester. In Java `matches` method, you do not need to use `^` or `$` to match the whole string, the match is anchored by default.

See the [**fixed regex fiddle**](https://regex101.com/r/twEQNK/2):

```
^[EC]D_V_[a-zA-Z]{5}____([0-9]{8})_[0-9]{3}_[a-zA-Z](_[0-9]{1,7})?\.([^.<>:”\/|*?]{3,4})(\.gz)?$
```

In Java, you may use

```
Boolean isValid = s.matches("[EC]D_V_[a-zA-Z]{5}____([0-9]{8})_[0-9]{3}_[a-zA-Z](_[0-9]{1,7})?\\.([^.<>:”/|*?]{3,4})(\\.gz)?");
```

Comment: I've updated the testdata too, and it looks good: 
https://regex101.com/r/twEQNK/4

Comment: Your regex is now failing the first testcase, see my fiddle.

Comment: @0x45 You have a trailing whitespace there, remove it. Are you using the pattern in `matches` method? Do you need to support leading/trailing whitespace? If yes, add `\s*` at the start/end of the pattern (after `^` and before `$` in the regex fiddle).

Comment: Just for interest, what was the problem with my regex now? Was my suspicion true?
No it's perfect like this, thanks.

Comment: @0x45 The problem you had was with the `^` anchor in the regex fiddle, but there was another problem with the 4th group, and that was more serious than the anchor issue, that is why I posted an answer.